# Calculate $\int_{-T}^T\sin(x-a)\cdot\sin(x-b)~e^{-k~(x-a)(x-b)}~dx\quad$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Calculate
$$\displaystyle\int_{-T}^T\sin(x-a)\cdot\sin(x-b)~e^{-k~(x-a)(x-b)}~dx\quad$$
I have no idea how to proceed. Any suggestions please? Here $T>0$.

Comment: $\sin t=\dfrac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$ doesn't help?

Comment: Yes, but I obtain a Gaussian integral. It is too hard for me.

Comment: what  is $k$ here?

Comment: the result containes the error function

Comment: You will get an error function type result because of the $-x^2$ in the argument of the exponential.

Comment: I do not see how you could avoid an error function in the complex domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the path to completion - not the answer. I will be assuming that $a,b,k$ - are real numbers.
First, observe that $$\sin(x-a)\sin(x-b) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(b-a)-\cos(2x-(a+b)))$$

Now, split integral in 3 parts:$$I_0 = \frac{\cos(a-b)}{2}\int_{-T}^{T}e^{-k((x-\frac{a+b}{2})^2 - \frac{a^2+b^2}{4})}dx$$ 
Other two integrals come from presentation of $\cos$ as a sum of two exponents: $$I_1 = -\frac{1}{4}\int_{-T}^{T}e^{-k((x-\frac{a+b}{2})^2 - \frac{a^2+b^2}{4}) + 2i(x - \frac{a+b}{2})}dx$$
$$I_2 = -\frac{1}{4}\int_{-T}^{T}e^{-k((x-\frac{a+b}{2})^2 - \frac{a^2+b^2}{4}) - 2i(x - \frac{a+b}{2})}dx$$

By variables substitution, $I_0$ can be presented as combination of error functions - $$erf(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt$$ if $k >0$ or Fresnel integrals if $k < 0$: $$C(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\cos(t^2)dt; S(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\sin(t^2)dt$$

In $I_1$ and $I_2$ substitute variables $u = x-\frac{a+b}{2}$ $$-ku^2 \pm 2iu = -(u\sqrt{k}\mp\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}})^2 - \frac{1}{k}$$ 
Let $y = u\sqrt{k}\mp\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}$

Now we will find that integration line shifted to complex plane.

All functions are analytic without poles on our contour and we can move line of the contour in a way to present integral as a sum of imaginary error functions.

Combining altogether gives us linear combination of error functions (or Fresnel functions, depends on k) and imaginary error functions.

Upon completion we shall pay attention to select right signs of imaginary parts to let them compensate as initial integral is real.

I would not dare to complete all above as it require lots of tedious computations.

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm trying to understand your demonstration. You say: "$I_0$ can be presented as combination of error functions if $k >0$ or Fresnel integrals if $k < 0$". But, what happens if $k=0$?

Comment: if $k = 0$ exponent disappears and integral is trivial, i.e. integrate $\cos$ on fixed line segment. I would recommend to start with simplest case (besides k = 0), i.e. let $k > 0$,carefully write all variable substitutions and changes in contour of integration - keeping function under sign of integral in simplest form (it shall end up in be $e^{-x^2}$). Then split integrals to the boundaries that defines error function (imaginary or regular).

Comment: Ok. What do you mean when you write "All functions are analytic without poles on our contour and we can move line of the contour in a way to present integral as a sum of imaginary error functions"? If my calculations are correct, $I_1$ for example should be rewritten as $-\frac{\sqrt \pi}{8\sqrt k}\left[\operatorname{erf}\left(\sqrt k\left(T-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)-\frac{i}{\sqrt k}\right) -   \operatorname{erf}\left(-\sqrt k\left(T+\frac{a+b}{2}\right)-\frac{i}{\sqrt k}\right) \right]$.

Comment: Your equation is correct. What I mean is that it all depends how you want to present the answer. $erf()$ function is defined for real arguments. Imaginary error function $erfi()$ is defined for imaginary argument and can be expressed using it real part thru Dawson integral and $erfi(x)=-ierf(ix)$. If we using arbitrary complex argument, we shall go to complex error function - $erfc(z)$. All of them can be expressed one thru another.

Comment: See the following links for more details: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712434/erfaib-error-function-separate-into-real-and-imaginary-part; or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259449/solve-an-integral-one-open-and-one-complex-limit - later link uses contour variation by integrating separately real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Here is a link to another article if interested in complex error functions and it behavior: http://www.unix.eng.ua.edu/~huddl/mystuff/ECE493/weidemen_complex_error_function.pdf